What is the source for Bitachon in the Torah?
The Chovos Halevovos's fourth שער, section, is on Bitachon. Since his sefer is "Duties of the heart", he clearly considers this a required "duty". Unlike some other areas, he does not have a sub-section where he gives the source for such a mitzvah.
There are many verses in Nach that do sound like they command Bitachon; some of them are at the end of Uva L'Tzion in the Shacharis davening.

בָּרוּךְ הַגֶּֽבֶר אֲשֶׁר יִבְטַח בה' וְהָיָה ה' מִבְטַחוֹ: בִּטְ֒חוּ
בה' עֲדֵי עַד כִּי בְּיָהּ ה' צוּר עוֹלָמִים: וְיִבְטְחוּ בְךָ
יוֹדְ֒עֵי שְׁמֶֽךָ כִּי לֺא עָזַֽבְתָּ דֹרְ֒שֶֽׁיךָ ה':

And more in Hallel:

יִ֭שְׂרָאֵל בְּטַ֣ח בה' עֶזְרָ֖ם וּמָגִנָּ֣ם הֽוּא׃
O Israel, trust
in the LORD! He is their help and shield.

And many others.
But I don't think there is such a verse in the Chumash, and (as far as I know) it isn't listed as one of the 613 mitzvos. Is there a source in Chumash?


Maybe it's a corollary of the obligation to serve G-d: כְּמוֹ שֶׁהָעֶבֶד חַיָּב לִבְטֹחַ עַל אֲדוֹנָיו

@JoelK Or the obligation of אמונה. That is indeed my impression from the Chazon Ish, Emunah uvitachon. He says something like, Emunah is the hashkafa, Bitachon is the practical halacha.

The root בטח can be found in Bereshis 34:25, Devarim 12:10, and Devarim 33:28. These could be the source, depending on one's definition of bitachon. What is the definition of the OP? It cannot be a mitzvah, it just means that we invest our efforts in doing mitzvos, relying that it is the right thing to do.

@YDJ None of these seems remotely like a source. The word betach, but in a completely different context.

@YDJ "It cannot be a mitzvah" Seems to me that the Chovos Halevavos obviously disagrees with you.

The context is different in English translation. Deseases also can be נאמנים, just like e-l melekh. It is possible, that the concept developed after Jewish people started living in Eretz Israel when living by the word of Torah became synonymous with security. In the desert in all likelihood it could not be learned. Hence the connection.

Note that he cites there the posuk ארור הגבר אשר יבטח באדם. It would hardly be possible to say that someone should be "cursed" unless that behavior was in fact wrong. (In other words, it's sort of an application of אין עונשין אלא אם בן מזהירין, and where sometimes indeed the fact that there's a punishment proves that there is indeed a prohibition.)

תמים תהיה עם ה׳ אלוקך?

@Meir, is this as answer to my question? The verse is from Jeremiah.

@Menachem Interesting. Rashi might sound that way: the nations go to fortune-tellers, but we don't need to do that. "walk before him whole-heartedly, put thy hope in Him and do not attempt to investigate the future, but whatever it may be that comes upon thee accept it whole-heartedly"

@Menachem True, but at least it does establish that there's an obligation (unlike the verses you cited, which could be understood to just be giving good advice for life). In fact that was how I understood (apparently wrongly) the thrust of your question.

"Since his sefer is 'Duties of the heart', he clearly considers this a required 'duty'." I'm not sure this premise is correct, especially in this case. In the שער introduction, he (or his translator) doesn't refer to 'Bitachon' as a 'חיוב/duty'. Contrast "בחיוב קבלת עבודת האלהים" with "מה שהוא צריך יותר מכל הדברים לעובד האלהים יתברך והוא הבטחון",...

...and with "מפני שקדם מאמרנו בבטחון על האלהים יתברך ראינו לסמך לו באור אפני חיוב היות כל מעשי העבודה מיחדים לאלהים לבדו" in the introduction to the next שער (note the absence of 'חיוב' when referring to "בטחון על האלהים יתברך").

According to the Semak, the source is the Mitzvah of Anochi: "I am the G-d your Lord who took you out of Egypt from the house of bondage."
We are commanded to believe that just as Hashem saved us then, He can save us now.

@MichoelR I added a link
